# How could I build an exe file in R

Tags: r

I write a function that works good. I want to build an exe file for it.
I search on the net, and I found this http://www.r-bloggers.com/making-r-files-executable-under-windows/. but something does not work on my windows. "Nothing show up to click on Yes"
I am using R version 3.2.3 on windows 7.
this is my function:

```
fun <- function(){
    x <- readline("Is it big?")
    if(x == "yes"){
        y <- readline("Is its neck tall?")
        if(y == "yes"){out <- "It is giraffe."}
        else{
            u <- readline("Does it have proboscis?")
            if(u == "yes"){out <- "It is elephant."}
            else{
                v <- readline("Is it aquatic?")
                if(v == "yes"){out <- "It is hippopotamus."}
                else{out <- "It is Rhino."}
            }}}
    else{
        z <- readline("Is it shreiking?")
        if (z=="yes"){out <- "It is mouse."}
        else {out <- "It is squirrel."}
    }
    return(out)
}

fun()
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Note the linked article is NOT about creating an exe file. Also your code does not run because you just define and not call any function. Just put a `fun()` after the last line.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you can't make .exe files from R script...if you want your code to be interactive try Shiny.